# Create a Dataset with some datas of a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Good Morning
Im trying create a new dataframe with some datas of another dataset (csv file in fact). In the code below, i put `df[1]` and `df[3]` because my intention is a new dataset with only these two columns of the csv file(second and forth column)
P.S: The original Dataset contains 75 columns
**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\krist\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Programação\Python\NFe_E_V3_00626708_20220801_20220830.csv', encoding='latin1', sep=';')


dfreduz = pd.DataFrame(df[1], df[3])

print(dfreduz)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one to select columns based on indexes:

```
dfreduz =  df.iloc[:, [1, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you would need to call the columns by name example:

```
dfreduz = pd.DataFrame(df["name"], df["job"])
```

make sure to use quotation marks `"`